# CPU usage always around 40% because of wait-chain?

Tags: networking, cpu, threads

I am facing a very rare problem and it's causing much trouble.
Whenever I boot my PC(HP 2000-2116tu, Win7, 4GB mem), there is a set of processes(legitimate ones and not virus), one of which starts to consume CPU and takes usage level to 40%. When I open the Resource Monitor, and right click on the process to analyze wait chain, this message is displayed- **One or more threads are waiting to finish network i/o**. If I end this process, then some other process takes over and exhibits the same behavior. **Note that only one process at a time does so**.This keeps on untill I end each of them one by one, but it is not a solution because I need those process as well.

**My CPU gets heat up very much** because of this excessive usage and the vents feel to be burning.

The Processes are:
**DCSHelper.exe**(data Card Monitor),
**Firefox.exe**(Mozilla Firefox),
**PhotonPlus.exe**(Mobile Internet Data Card Process),
**Nclmbtr.exe**(Microsoft Bluetooth Server),
**jusched.exe**(Java Update Scheduler), and many more similar ones.

One common thing I noticed about these processes is that all these interact with external Devices/interfaces/network. 
I use Microsoft Security Essentials and have run a full scan but no good it did.
Please help if someone is aware of such an issue.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use any other firewall, anti-virus or anti-malware programs (including browser add ons).

Comment: MSCONFIG - disable all the programs you don't want to start up (this may include this process)! Then add them one at a time to find the faulty process (or manually kill them in task manager one at a time which is less hassle than a reboot!)